# Is complex field validation possible with WebForm?

Tags: webforms

[WebForm](http://drupal.org/project/webform) is a *very* nicely done module, but (at least at first glance) it seems to lack some things that I expect to need.

Specifically, I'd like a way to specify more complex field requirements than just a boolean.  For instance, what if I have a form with an e-mail address field and a telephone field, and I want the user to be required to enter at least one of the two.  In other words, if they enter an e-mail address, they don't need to enter a phone number; and if they enter a phone number, they don't need to enter an e-mail address.

Is this possible with WebForm?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [WebForm Validation module](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation).

> The following validation rules are currently included:
>
> - Numeric values (optionally specify min and / or max value)
> - Minimum length
> - Maximum length
> - Minimum number of words
> - Maximum number of words
> - Equal values on multiple fields
> - Unique values on multiple fields
> - Specific value
> - ***Require at least one of two fields***
> - ***Require at least one of several fields***
> - Minimum number of selections required
> - Maximum number of selections allowed
> - Exact number of selections required
> - Plain text (disallow tags)
> - Regular expression
> - Must be empty (Anti-Spam: Hide with CSS)
> - Words blacklist
> - Must match a username

Answer (score 1):

If your validation logic is complex it might be better to do that through a custom module.

There are three ways:

1. Regular `hook_form_alter()` and adding your validation callback to the `$form['#validate']` array.
2. Implement `hook_webform_validation_validators()`.
3. Implement `hook_webform_validation_validate()`.

See [this article](http://drupal.org/node/908600) for more information about 2. and 3.